# MSDE backup file is appending

Tags: backup, msde

I have an MSDE 2000 database backup file which is appending rather than deleting or renaming.  I am using this command:
BACKUP DATABASE [SPSDB] TO  DISK = 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\BACKUP\SPSbackup\spsdb.bak' with retaindays = 1

I am using a maintenance plan on my full SQL version databases, and they create a new file everyday with the date in the file name.

The backup file size creeps up on me if I don't monitor it. Is there a way to have MSDE make a uniue file with the daily backup job I created?

Thanks,
Chad

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx for the `BACKUP` command. Did you try using `INIT` option?

I noticed the question is very old, but maybe my answer can help somenone.